# iOS XCode build error (flutter) -- cannot build apk for iOS (flutter) on mac with M1 chip

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build

I'm using a MacBook Pro with M1 chip to test a flutter app, but I am unable to do so in both a physical IOS device as well as the simulator.
I'm getting the following error:

****objc[6039]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1f47f78f0) and ?? (0x1149942b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[6039]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1f47f7940) and ?? (0x114994308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
** BUILD FAILED ******

My flutter project is returning the following error:

*Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error launching application on iPhone.*

XCode's Output is as follows:
*No profiles for 'juniorsdelivery.juniors-app' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'juniorsdelivery.juniors-app'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')*

I've tried what other people facing these problem have posted here on stack overflow, but none of these seems to work. I've tried running 'pod install', deleting and editing Runner files, and setting the *Debug* and *Release* under the 'Code Signing identity' to 'any IOS SDK'.
Please help! And thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO, this has nothing to do with the M1 chip The error is clearly saying `Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'juniorsdelivery.juniors-app'`.

[This answer should solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65192512/flutter-error-no-profiles-for-xxx-were-found-xcode-couldn-t-find-any-ios-app). You have to configure your provisioning profile in X-code.